# executable is not created during makefile execution

Tags: c

```
#! bin/bash
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I.
DEPS=p.h

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
hello:p1.o p2.o
        gcc hello p1.o p2.o -I.
```

***the error showing during the the make of makefile is shown below***

```
gcc hello p1.o p2.o -I.
gcc: error: hello: No such file or directory
make: *** [hello] Error 1
```

***executable is not created after makefile execution,but the obnject files are created***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `gcc hello p1.o p2.o -I.` to `gcc p1.o p2.o -o hello`

Answer (score 1):

If your output is `hello`, change to

```
hello:p1.o p2.o
    gcc p1.o p2.o -I. -o $@
```